# Hibernate multiple many-to-one mappings

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have a job table which has multiple many-to-one mappings. A applicants table which has applicants for a specific job and address table which has multiple places about where this job is posted. I am looking for a query which gets me list of jobs (without multiple entries for each job). When I do job.getApplicants it should give me all the applicants list for that job and job.addresses should give me all the addresses for this job. The important this is all the above data should be obtained in **One Single Eager** fetch.

The problem I have now is that I am getting 10 entries for single job in my jobList if I have 10 applicants. The code I am using is somewhat like this.

```
select j from Job j left outer join fetch j.applicants apps where j.job_id = :job_id
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the answer was very simple.. I just have to add distinct like

```
select distinct j from Job
```

I could not use distinct before because one of the columns in job was of type xml.. I am still looking for answer on how to cast xml type column to a String/varchar while creating the entity class itself, while mapping with annotations.